# Python Pandas recursively divide columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns, and I want to divide column `a` by `b` and `c` and any other columns `c, d, e, f, ...` that come after it.

I've been thinking about using `dataframe.agg` and `functools.reduce`.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
c = [1,2,3,4,5]

frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post the expected output? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something like this works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from functools import reduce

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
c = [1,2,3,4,5]

frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})

frame.agg(lambda x: reduce(np.divide, x), axis=1)
```